Parallel coordinates plot with some lines dotted
I'm trying to make a parallel coordinate plot in Python with lines that fall into two categories. I was hoping to plot them all together, but make lines for one category dotted so you can tell the difference. I was using Plotly but it looks like it doesn't support modifying lines like that. Would any other tools support this? I was thinking about Pandas but couldn't find information on whether Pandas would support this. Thank you!
Edit: My data will have axes at different scales, with one axis in the billions and another less than 1. The ability to handle these differing scales on the same plot would be helpful
